# Python: sort,groupby or concatenate by date without changing index order

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, concatenation, pandas-groupby

I want to sort/groupby/concatenate data in a list by date, but without changing the order.
I have the following list stored in

```
loop_1 = []
```

and the sample data in loop_1 is the following:

[image]

I want to achieve this:

[image]

I've tried:

```
df = pd.concat(loop_1,axis=1)
```

also:

```
df = pd.concat(loop_1)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df = df.groupby(['date']).first()
```

also:

```
df = pd.concat(loop_1)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df = df.groupby(['date'] sort=False).first()
```

but still cannot achieve the desired result.

Comment: I think you need to `merge` `outer` those 2 dataframe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101

Comment: Your source data is in a list, you say ?  How does it look like ? Your like shown is empty loop_1 = []

Comment: It is stored in loop_1 -> loop_1.append(data).

Comment: Please  show sample data in list `loop_1`.

Comment: I edited the post which shows the sample data in list loop_1.

Comment: Your date format is difficult to sort them in sequence.  What's the year you assume for dates in December and what's year for dates in January ?

Comment: In the original code 15 different loops occur and every loop is for different period (first is Dec 2006-Jan 2007, second is Dec 2007-Jan 2008, third is Dec 2008-Jan 2009 and so long). After every loop I sort the result in loop_1. After the final loop is completed I want to sort the values in loop_1 by Month and Day but also to keep the Dec-Jan order (as shown in the desired outcome). Date format is like that because I want to sort/group the values by month and day.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this result by using the pandas merge function.

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on='date', how='outer')
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The problem is that I have a list stored in loop_1 and not separate dataframes.

Comment: @kobo I'd suggest making it a Pandas DataFrame to make it easier to work with.
If you show what loop_1 looks like, I might be able to help.
It looks like they're 2 columns, but you say it's 1. How are they separated?

Comment: I edited the post which shows the sample data in list loop_1. In the original code 15 different loops occur and every loop is for different period (first is Dec 2006-Jan 2007, second is Dec 2007-Jan 2008, third is Dec 2008-Jan 2009 and so long). After every loop I sort the result in loop_1. After the final loop is completed I want to sort the values in loop_1 by Month and Day but also to keep the Dec-Jan order (as shown in the desired outcome).